# SQL SYNTAX - data type error. How to cast?

Tags: sql, netsuite

I have the following code:

```
CASE WHEN {internalid} = {test} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

But when I run it, i received the following error:

Your formula has an error in it. It could resolve to the wrong datatype, use an unknown function, or have a syntax error. Please go back, correct the formula, and re-submit.

Is there a way I can cast it so it will have same data type no matter what?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use the cast function

```
-- CAST ( { expression | NULL } AS data_type [(length)] )
CASE 
   WHEN CAST ({internalid} as VARCHAR(20)) = CAST({test}as VARCHAR(20))
   THEN 1 
   ELSE 0 
END;
```